# Group values that have the same name in one column and same id in other column

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have the following situation:

With my current query this is how I get my data:

[image]

The problem is that I want to combine `straat` and `plaatsnaam` and read them as one row. Each `straat` has the same `value_item_id` as its `plaatsnaam` counterpart.

Is it possible to take `straat` and `plaatsnaam` and group them together by their `value_item_id` ?

My current query looks like this:

```
SELECT fields.id as field_id,
       fields.name,
       fields_categories.field_id as catfield_id,
       fields_values.field_id as fieldvalue_id,
       fields_values.item_id as value_item_id,
       fields_values.value,
       content.id as content_id
FROM snm_fields fields
INNER JOIN snm_fields_categories fields_categories
ON fields.id = fields_categories.field_id
INNER JOIN snm_fields_values fields_values
ON fields_categories.field_id = fields_values.field_id
INNER JOIN snm_content content
ON content.id = fields_values.item_id
WHERE fields.name in ('straat', 'plaatsnaam')
```

In the end I want to have `Ridderstraat 5` and `Heenvliet` in the same row. I know this can also be done with PHP, but I think doing this directly with SQL is better.

Comment: sample output please

Comment: what is your desired results? what do you do with the `Id`s that are different?

Comment: use group_concat on name and value fields and group by all the other fields in the select.

Comment: Is fieldvalue_Id and content_ID always the same?

Comment: @xQbert Yes always

Comment: Group_concat or join depending on desired expected results.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think 'doing this directly with SQL is better'. I think it's significantly worse!

Comment: @Strawberry Why? It saves code so it should make it faster right? Instead of getting data from my database and then applying some php function to it I now directly get the data how I want from the database.

Comment: @twan That would only be true if you weren't then parsing the data in PHP. As it is, your existing method is much more flexible, and easily scalable - even allowing the formatting to take place client side (in javascript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you simply want the plaats and straat per `item_id`. If so, it suffices to read from tables `snm_fields` and `snm_fields_values` only. Using conditional aggregation per `item_id`:

```
select 
  fv.item_id, 
  max(case when f.name = 'plaatsnaam' then fv.value end) as plaats,
  max(case when f.name = 'straat' then fv.value end) as straat
from snm_fields_values fv 
join snm_fields f on f.id = fv.field_id
group by fv.item_id
order by fv.item_id, plaats, straat;
```

Or, if it's okay for you to have your query know the IDs, even:

```
select 
  item_id, 
  max(case when field_id = 3 then value end) as plaats,
  max(case when field_id = 1 then value end) as straat
from snm_fields_values
group by item_id
order by item_id, plaats, straat;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the result I needed!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a join  on the filtered  tables

```
  SELECT 
        fields1.id as field_id
      , fields1.name
      , fields1_categories.field_id as catfield_id
      , fields1_values.field_id as fieldvalue_id
      , fields1_values.item_id as value_item_id
      , fields1_values.value
      , content.id as content_id
      , fields2.id as field_id
      , fields2.name
      , fields2_categories.field_id as catfield_id
      , fields2_values.field_id as fieldvalue_id
      , fields2_values.item_id as value_item_id
      , fields2_values.value
  FROM snm_fields fields1
  INNER JOIN (
      SELECT 
            fields.id as field_id
          , fields.name
          , fields_categories.field_id as catfield_id
          , fields_values.field_id as fieldvalue_id
          , fields_values.item_id as value_item_id
          , fields_values.value
      FROM snm_fields fields
      WHERE fields.name  = 'plaatsnaam')

    ) on field2  ON field1.value_item_id = field2.value_item_id
  INNER JOIN snm_fields_categories fields_categories ON fields.id = fields_categories.field_id
  INNER JOIN snm_content content
  WHERE fields.name = 'straat'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function.

```
SELECT value_item_id,
      GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR ' ') as grouped_name,
      GROUP_CONCAT(value SEPARATOR ' ') as grouped_value,
FROM (the_query) src
GROUP BY value_item_id
```